# Select failed: pq: relation "signers" does not exist

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, javascript-sdk

I have set up private Stellar Core and Horizon with 2 nodes. I am following [this tutorial](https://labs.imaginea.com/post/stellar-bc-wallet/). I am first creating an account and then I am executing the code below. It is showing `select failed: pq: relation "signers" does not exist"` on the Horizon console.

Attached is the screenshot of error. I am a newbie. Kindly suggest how I can resolve the issue.
[image: error image here]

```
  const HORIZON_ENDPOINT = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';
  Stellar.Network.use(new Stellar.Network(NETWORK_PASSPHRASE));
  var opts = new Stellar.Config.setAllowHttp(true);
  var server = new Stellar.Server(HORIZON_ENDPOINT, opts);

  let sourceKeys = Stellar.Keypair.fromSecret("SCZ5WJ7ZTEM7CS3KDM7KZSI7YEBXMU52JJV7ETRUTGCDI7WFWRAXP3KF");
        console.log("1");
        // loading root account
        server.loadAccount(sourceKeys.publicKey())
        .then(function(sourceAccount) {

            let txn = new Stellar.TransactionBuilder(sourceAccount)
                        .addOperation(
                            Stellar.Operation.createAccount({
                            destination: pk,
                            startingBalance: "100"}))
                        .addMemo(Stellar.Memo.text('Test Transaction'))
                        .build();
            txn.sign(sourceKeys);
            return server.submitTransaction(txn);
            })
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log({"Msg" : `SUCCESS : ${JSON.stringify(result)}`})
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Something went wrong!', error);
            console.log({"Msg" : `ERROR in inner catch statement`})
        });
```

Comment: could you check 2 things? (1) Stellar-Core has a "Sync!" (running) status; (2) Horizon has its DB initialized

Comment: @cesarm you can checkout this url https://pasteboard.co/IaZS7eq.png which can give a confirmation that the stellar-core are sync

Comment: @cesarm check this liink that whether my horizon db is initialised https://pasteboard.co/IaZSPdD.png

Comment: The signers table was in the stellar-core database and deprecated + removed in stellar-core 10.3.0 (it's now a column in accounts). An upgrade of stellar-horizon to v0.17.4 (or downgrade stellar-core to 10.2) should fix it.

Comment: Ah, and the stellar-horizon repository has moved. If you followed the link in that tutorial you probably installed v0.11.1 here is the actual release https://github.com/stellar/go/releases/tag/horizon-v0.17.4

Comment: @sui Thanks for replying. I have upgraded the stellar horizon db. Initialised again but now it is giving this error. here is the link https://pasteboard.co/Ib0EPsO.png.
Also, i am using this tutorial as reference https://labs.imaginea.com/post/stellar-bc-wallet/

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92682/discussion-on-question-by-suman-raj-select-failed-pq-relation-signers-does-n).

Comment: Welcome Suman Raj. In the future, please copy and paste error messages rather than use images. This helps people answer your question and improves the chances of people with a similar problem finding this question.